# Error linking GLEW under MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut, glew

I am going through [this OGL tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html).

I've installed GLUT according to [here](http://aschultz.us/blog/archives/176);
I've installed GLEW according to their instruction on sourceforge.net

I've added to preprocessor definitions: `GLEW_STATIC`.

I've added to linker Input dependencies: `opengl32.lib; glu32.lib; glut32.lib; glew32s.lib`.

I'm including all the proper headers:

```
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
```

But there is still a linker error:

```
1> ------ Build started: Project: OGL-Tutorial, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
1> OGL-Tutorial.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray 
1> c:\users\robert\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OGL-Tutorial\Debu\OGL-Tutorial.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There have been quite a few very similar questions, and I have read and tried to apply the solutions, but I still cannot figure out what it is that I am doing wrong.